# Should I write my full name on license files?

Tags: copyright, software

I'm a software developer and currently working on some projects.

I want to protect them by adding LICENSE files inside the projects. This files will contain a simple line:

> (C) Copyright 2017 [NAME], all rights reserved.

It is common practice when developing software to add LICENSE files in your source code.

I am spanish, so I have a name, and 2 surnames.

My question is, should I write my name and my 2 surnames, or can I get away with just 1 surname?

I would like to use only my first surname, but I don't know if that would be as "safe" as using both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to put a copyright notice anywhere to protect things in which you have copyright - "all rights reserved" is the default assumption.

The only reason to put your name and a copyright notice in there is to make it clear in future actions that you do, in fact, own the copyright - but this is not the only way to do this (e.g.  GitHub repository will also do this). Any way that identifies *you* is fine.